# IIS on AWS Windows Server 2016 not serving to external clients

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, windows-server-2016, windows-firewall, security-groups

I created an AWS Windows Server 2016 instance and also allocated an elastic IP address to it. Server's running fine and I can RDP into it.

I also installed IIS on it and ensured that it is running. Just to be sure, I explicitly enabled ports 80 and 443 on the Windows Firewall.

I added a default page ("index.html") to the default website, and when I visited the page using IE on the server with the address *localhost*, the page displayed fine. But when I am trying to access the same page using the elastic IP address, it is showing a timeout error (ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT).

I also made sure that I added outbound exception rules to the AWS security groups as in the image below.

[image]

But still the same error.

I just cannot figure out where I am going wrong.

Comment: The outbound rule isn't what you need. What do the inbound rules look like?

Comment: @joeqwerty, I got what you were getting at. I added exceptions to both, ports 80 and 443 in the inbound rules, and now it's serving perfectly. Thanks so much (y)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the inbound rules to All Traffic (0.0.0.0/0) can make it work in the local system using the public IP address